# How can I take n-documents for each query in a nested query?

Tags: elasticsearch

I currently have a document type that has an array of string identifiers stored in Elasticsearch. I would now like to search for many companies worth of identifiers at once -- which is easy enough, I was just able to tell ES to match on **any** of the identifiers by providing a combined list of all identifiers.

Now, I would like to tell ES to match 5 documents of each group of identifiers. For example, if I had the following items stored:

```
{ text: "Goodbye!", Identifiers: [q]}
{ text: "So long!", Identifiers: [a]}
{ text: "Goodnight!", Identifiers: [a, z]}
{ text: "See you tomorrow!", Identifiers: [b, r]}
{ text: "Farewell!", Identifiers: [c, b, d, m]}
```

I want to provide several queries and have each return only 1 element for each group. So if I searched for items grouped in either (don't really care about overlap):

```
[d], [b, z, r], [d, r]
```

I would expect to get back:

```
{ text: "Farewell!", Identifiers: [c, b, d, m]}
{ text: "Goodnight!", Identifiers: [a, z]}
{ text: "See you tomorrow!", Identifiers: [b, r]}
```

The first, because it matched on `d`, the second because it matched on `z`, the third because it matched on `b`.

Is this, at all possible to perform in one query, or am I going to have to query once per group to achieve this?

Comment: I did not fully understand what you are trying to do, but maybe you could use a boolean query with OR and then make each group a subquery.

Comment: I am essentially trying to do what you just said, but instead of setting a "take" of '1' on the *whole* query, I want a "take" of '1' on every subquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [mulitsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html) allows you to search for n-documents in each query.